# Fixing PHP Codeigniter Pagination button

Tags: codeigniter-3, php-5.6

I am now trying to modify the pagination library in version 3.1 of codeigniter.

This is the numbering of the pagination currently in use by default.

My Controller:

```
$config['num_links'] = 2;
```

**Example**:

**1**234 > >>

4 page button click

123**4**567 > >>

**What I want** :

**1**2345 > >>

4 page button click

123**4**5 > >>

I am now trying to modify the pagination library in version 3.1 of codeigniter.

This is the numbering of the pagination currently in use by default.

what I want

As you can see in the example, the page button is not static.
All I want is to have the page button fixed and move to the next range only when I click on the icon.
I am trying to do this in version codeigniter3.1 and I do not know how to modify the pagination class. Please help me.

Comment: Edit your question and add controller code of pagination.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code  and  refer 
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/pagination.html

```
$config["base_url"] = base_url().'example';
$config["total_rows"] = $count;//total number of result
$config["per_page"] = 5;
$config["uri_segment"] = 2;
$config['use_page_numbers'] = true;

$this->pagination->initialize($config);

$page_num = $this->uri->segment(2, 0);
$offset = ($page_num ? ($page_num - 1) * $config['per_page'] : 0);

$results = $this->product_file->select($config["per_page"], $offset);
$links = $this->pagination->create_links();
```